# I can't understand what XlSaveAsAccessMode is, can someone explain it?

Tags: excel

I need to know how this enumeration works, but consulting the documentation was not very helpful. I know it's a parameter for saving an Excel workbook and I know it goes from 1-3.

This doesn't help me understand the difference however and I can't seem to find any resources that do so. I would be very grateful if anyone can explain to me what this is used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XlSaveAsAccessMode Enumeration (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195297.aspx) has:

> ```
> Name          Value     Description
>
> xlExclusive     3        Exclusive mode
>
> xlNoChange      1        Default (does not change the access mode)
>
> xlShared        2        Share list
> ```

I think basically just a control over whether another instance/application may or may not write to the file during its save operation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was very helpful!